# AdWhirl rotation usage

Tags: iphone, adwhirl

Im trying to rotate the AdWhirl bannerview. The only documentation AdWhirl provides is:

> 6.2 Device Orientation
>   Some ad networks including iAd will vary their ad dimensions with device orientation.
>   If your app supports rotation you must forward orientation changes to AdWhirlView by invoking AdWhirlView.rotateToOrientation: within your UIViewController’s should/willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: implementation and then refit as per 6.1.
>   If your app’s notion of orientation somehow differs from UIDevice.orientation you must also implement AdWhirlDelegate.adWhirlCurrentOrientation to return the appropriate value.

I'm trying to figure this out and so far correctly implemented the adWhirlDidReceiveAd method but I can't correctly rotate and/or resize the ad in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set AdWhirl at the bottom of the view: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756346/adwhirl-admob-iad-ads-not-showing-in-released-iphone-app/7784388#7784388)

Make the ad static when scrolling (i.e. TableView): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537858/iphone-need-to-put-uiview-on-top-of-uitableview-in-fixed-position/7784987#7784987)

This is how I rotate ads with AdWhirl (probably not the best solution...):

```
    awView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    awView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(-90));
    awView.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320);
```

You'll need to change the coordinates depending on your view.

Comment: Is this the correct way to do so bcoz m not able to get the desire results ?

Answer (score 1):

[AdWhirlView rotateToOrientation] calls `rotateToOrientation` method for each current network adapter.
However, some network adapter does't override this method. Default implementation of this method does nothing.
So, you need to override rotateToOrientation method.

Next is a sample implementation for network adapter for AdMob.

AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds.m

```
-(void)rotateToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

    GADBannerView* adMobView;
    adMobView = (GADBannerView*)adNetworkView;

    switch (orientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            adMobView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            adMobView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your UIViewController implementation, add the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: like so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation is supported)
    {
        [adWhirlView_ rotateToOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Note that as long as shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: is implemented, the AdWhirlView will rotate with the rest of the layout.  However, calling rotateToOrientation: will tell the AdWhirlView to forward an orientation change signal to the ad so that an individual ad network can optimize the ad for landscape if it chooses.

Comment: I noticed that it rotates with the screen, but it doesn't resize the ad yet.

Comment: By the way, i cant find anywhere in the documentation how to place the ad at the bottom of the view, and make it static in the screen, so that you cant scroll it out of view.

Comment: in defination of rotateToOrientation currAdapter is always nil in my case ..... it always returns before setting the orientation