# AdWhirl (AdMob, iAd) Ads not showing in released iPhone App

Tags: iphone, admob, iad, adwhirl

I have developed my first App which is free of charge ("Aviation DG"),
and thus added adWhirl to it. However it seems that I have done
something wrong. There are no ads showing at all. (Settings in AdWhirl: 90% iAd / 10% AdMob / 10% for 1 House Ad). I don't see any of them :(

In iAd i have 45 requests 0 impressions, in AdMob i have 152 requests
152 impressions, however they are not showing any ads (at least those
people I have asked if they see the ads).

When I tested the app, it showed the Banner iAD Test (or whatever it
says, the black banner from apple).

Do you know what I could have done wrong? Or are the things correctly
installed and I just dont receive any ads. If so, why is that?

Thanks so much in advance for your help. This might be just a small
project at the moment, but I intend to add Ad networks to other apps
to and it would be nice to know why it's not working :)

Cheers
Ronnie

**Following is what I have done in xcode:**

Added the folowing frameworks:

iAd / AVFoundation / CoreLocation / AddressBook / AudioToolbox /
MapKit / MediaPlayer / MessageUI / QuartzCore / SystemConfiguration /
libsqlite3.dylib / libz.dylib

Added the Folder TouchJSON, added the Folder AdWhirl from AdWhirl
Ressources.

As I didn't find the Adapter settings as in the instruction PDF, I
deleted all networks and have now the following files in the adapters
folder:

- AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds.h/.m
- AdWhirlAdapterIAd.h/.m
- AdWhirlAdNetworkAdapter.h

Then I aded the AdLibrary from adMob:

- GADBannerView.h
- GADBannerViewDelegate.h
- GADInterstitial.h
- GADInterstitialDelegate.h
- GADRequest.h
- GADRequestError.h
- libGoogleAdMobAds.a

Then I have changed the following part (in AdWhirlView.h), that the ad
shows on the bottom of the page:

```
#define kAdWhirlAppVer 300

#define kAdWhirlViewWidth 320
#define kAdWhirlViewHeight 50
#define kAdWhirlViewDefaultSize \
                       (CGSizeMake(kAdWhirlViewWidth,
kAdWhirlViewHeight))
#define kAdWhirlViewDefaultFrame \
                       (CGRectMake(0,(460-
kAdWhirlViewHeight),kAdWhirlViewWidth, kAdWhirlViewHeight))

#define kAdWhirlDefaultConfigURL @"http://mob.adwhirl.com/getInfo.php"
#define kAdWhirlDefaultImpMetricURL @"http://met.adwhirl.com/
exmet.php"
#define kAdWhirlDefaultClickMetricURL @"http://met.adwhirl.com/
exclick.php"
#define kAdWhirlDefaultCustomAdURL @"http://mob.adwhirl.com/
custom.php"
#define kAWMinimumTimeBetweenFreshAdRequests 4.9f
#define kAdWhirlAdRequestTimeout 10
```

in my view controller .m file I then have this:

```
#define kSampleAppKey @"x000x00000000x00000x000x0000x000" //the number
of my adwhirl appid

@implementation...

#pragma mark AdWhirlDelegate methods

- (NSString *)adWhirlApplicationKey{
   return kSampleAppKey;
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView{
   return self;
}
```

in the view did load:

```
   AdWhirlView *awView = [AdWhirlView
requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];

   [self.view addSubview:awView];

   [super viewDidLoad];
```

in the viewcontroller .h file:

```
#import "AdWhirlView.h"
#import "AdWhirlDelegateProtocol.h"

@interface Aviation_DGViewController : UIViewController
<ItemChooserDelegate, InfoDisplayDelegate, AdWhirlDelegate> {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change `AdWhirlView.h`:

`#define kAdWhirlViewDefaultFrame (CGRectMake(0,(460-kAdWhirlViewHeight),kAdWhirlViewWidth, kAdWhirlViewHeight))`

You can have the ad at the bottom by playing with the coordinates, but what's behind the whole upper part of the screen will be inactive. So, leave it as:

`#define kAdWhirlViewDefaultFrame (CGRectMake(0,0,kAdWhirlViewWidth, kAdWhirlViewHeight))`

Instead, in `-(void)viewDidLoad`, center `awView` with `awView.center`:

`AdWhirlView *awView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];`

awView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height-kAdWhirlViewHeight/2);

[self.view addSubview:awView];

Answer (score 0):

Fill rates for iAds can be low at times especially if you don't have thousands of ad requests a day. It depends upon the country etc.

If you were seeing the iAds test ad in development then I suspect you have done nothing wrong.

I trust that you have downloaded your own app and are seeing house ads?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, how long do I have to wait to see house ads? As I don't see any of those.

Comment: no problem :) hope anybody else knows an answer, this is going on my nerves :D At least it is not working on an app with 100'000 downloads :D but like 10 or something, so enough time do an update if anybody knows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm from the code you posted that you set up AdWhirl correctly.  I don't know what you're doing with the kAWMinimumTimeBetweenFreshAdRequests and kAdWhirlAdRequestTimeout, but what happens if don't set these values?

House Ads should be ready right away.  This assumes you created a house ad and set it to show in your app.  I would recommend trafficking 1 network at a time for testing (such as 100% house ads), and see if you get them.

Comment: the kAWMinimumTimeBetweenFreshAdRequests and kAdWhirlAdRequestTimeout, I did not touch :) only thing I changed there is the part #define kAdWhirlViewDefaultFrame \
                       (CGRectMake(0,(460-
kAdWhirlViewHeight),kAdWhirlViewWidth, kAdWhirlViewHeight))

Comment: Oh, and I tried yesterday to only set house adds as 100%, no iAds and no AdMobs, still I did not see anything on my iPhone nor did my brother on his. It's really weird, shouldn't I at least see my house ads? I did upload 3 sizes of house adds (.png Banner files) and hooked it up with AdWhirl to this project. It seems that the connection is there, otherwise AdMob and iAd would not count the requests right?

Comment: In iOS, the config is fetched with the first ad request each time the application is launched.  So it should be updating your settings when you re-run the application.  If you are seeing AdMob and iAd requests than you must have the code implemented correctly; I think it is an issue setting it up in the AdWhirl UI.  Click your app and under "App Network settings" make sure house ads are on and have 100% traffic (looks like you did this).  Then in your app under "House Ads", make sure you have house ads there and that they sum up to 100% allocation.