# UITableView Being Covered by Custom Calendar View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, calendar

I have a custom calendar view in my self.view and a UITableView on the bottom. When the calendar days exceed XXX amount, it covers the UITableView. Is there a way I can attach the UITableView to the bottom of the custom calendar view?

This is the code generating my Custom Calendar View in my viewDidLoad method.

```
calendar = [[VRGCalendarView alloc] init];
calendar.delegate=self;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:calendar];
[self.view addSubview:calendar];
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding a custom class method in my CalendarView.m...

```
[self.delegate calendarView:self didchangedHeight:self.frameHeight];
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer, I think it can help better than my original posts: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784987/295212