# Need assistance showing custom UIView when UITableView is dried down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to achieve `whatsapp` style `drag tableview` to show custom `view`, here is the screenshot

[image]

but I am clueless how to show custom `UIView` on top of `UITableView` when `UITableView` is dragged down

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537858/iphone-need-to-put-uiview-on-top-of-uitableview-in-fixed-position

Answer (score 0):

You can place your UIView behind the table view, and have its height grow as you drag down. Where you read the scroll offset for your table views scroll delegate.